# Why would my page have different dimensions when run from the server?

Tags: html, node.js, express, svg, raphael

file:///Users/dg/Google%20Drive/code/websites/Q-Po/qpo/client/index.html
I have a page. When I access it from my local file system (via file:///*), pull up my developer console in Chrome, and type window.innerWidth, the result is 1162.

When I serve the same page from a Node server in the cloud via Express.js, like this...

```
var express = require('express'); //Require express for middleware use
const app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http); //IO is the server

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../client")); //Serve static files

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('./index.html');
});
```

... and then access it my browser at [url].com, I get window.innerWidth = 1278.

This apparently causes the served version of the page to scale down svg elements slightly (shown below.)

What gives?

[image: run locally]
local page (clipped horizontally -- focus on difference in scaling of elements in center between this and the below image:)

[image: pulled from server]
served page (also clipped horizontally)

**The svg containers in the middle of the page are both 600x600, according to the element inspector, but they render at different actual sizes on my screen. How can this be?**

Comment: Both of those images are different sizes. Are you sure you didn't resize chrome? Was the developer console docked, as that changes the size? Compare the `view-source:` as well.

Comment: I'm sure I didn't resize Chrome. The console was docked in both instances, (only changes vertical sizes.)

Comment: @DJG - There's something different between environments, try using a local server instead of file:// maybe http-server or browser-sync as they are node based.